# Can anyone identify this tree with green berries?

Tags: identification, trees, berries, poisons, edible

Found in mid-Missouri, pictures taken August 12th. What is this tree? Are the berries edible? I can't imagine they are unless they're just not ripe yet. My grandpa wants to know before he cuts it down.

[image: mystery tree berries]

[image: mystery tree leaves]

[image: mystery tree bark]

Comment: No clue. Berries look like Poison Ivy. Leaves look like grape vine. But berries *are* turning purple on the right.

Comment: "Berries" are not from the tree. The grapevine hypothesis appears to be correct.

Comment: @Ecnerwal - what do you mean by "berries are not from the tree"? I was assuming (quite possibly in error) that the bottom picture is of a mature vine trunk.

Comment: Are the berries and the trunk definitely part of the same plant?

Comment: @Peter4075 the bark in the first picture looks like a vine (the stems and leaves are compatible too), but in the last picture it doesn't look much like my vine or the first picture. The bark is too thick for starters.  I wonder if there's a vine growing up standing deadwood.

Comment: What does the inside of a berry look like?

Comment: @ChrisH - Agreed. The bark doesn't look "shaggy" enough for a grape vine.

Answer (score 7):

It's a wild grape vine, muscadine or something similar.

[image]

https://dendro.cnre.vt.edu/dendrology/syllabus/factsheet.cfm?ID=654

Answer (score 1):

I agree it's a wild grape. I used the free Plantnet app to identify it onscreen.

Answer (score 0):

They're **Turkey Berries**!

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solanum_torvum

[image: Turkey Berries / Sundakkai (Tamizh)]

In terms of Ayurveda they're incredibly healthy for you and its often used to make an extremely scrumptious dish called [Sundakkai Karakuzhambu](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-B8tYXfpuHw) (with either slightly fresh crushed berries but most often they're just sun dried to be used whenever you want).

While fresh berries are somewhat sweet, the sun dried ones are more bitter and rustic tasting (its an acquired taste)

Comment: Hmmm... you think so?  The edges of the leaves don't look like *solanum torvum*, and also the crowns aren't present on the berries in the OP's images.  Also the stems for each berry in the OP's photos don't look like those for *solanum torvum*.  What do you think?

Comment: Well, another identifying feature can be that Turkey Berry shrubs have thorns! The leaves do look similar (since I grow these plants at home :D) but yes, look out for thorny stems/branches and white flowers, they're a tell-a-tale sign.

Cheers

Comment: Maybe you could have provided a better source?  Because the image on the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solanum_torvum#/media/File:Solanum_torvum_2.jpg) really doesn't look anything like the plant in the question.